# What does 'pulling out all the stops' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I don't grasp the following sentence:

> "After years of raking in huge sums of oil money, these days Saudi Arabia is pulling out all the stops to raise cash. "

What stops do they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["*Pulling out all the stops*"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull_out_all_the_stops) is an idiom related to the playing of a church organ.

A pipe organ in a church is controlled by, amongst other things, [stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_stop) which affect the flow of air to control the volume of the sound.

Pulling out a stop removes a restriction and so makes the sound louder.  An organ will have many stops, so pulling them all out gives maximum sound.

[image: Church organ stops]

Thus the idiom means to apply maximum effort.

Comment: *Raking in X* means that X is free for the taking, or very easy to get, and that you are acquiring large quantities of X.  As though X were leaves on the ground.

Comment: Specifically, the stops control airflow to different banks of pipes with different sounds - effectively different instruments. Pulling out all the stops plays all sets of pipes at once - you are using everything, doing everything possible.